# How I can check if a port is in TIME_WAIT status or already taken by another application

Tags: c++, c, linux, sockets, unix

I developed a service which contains a tcp server.

When I restart my application, sometime my application is unable to bind the port for the [TIME_WAIT](http://www.softlab.ntua.gr/facilities/documentation/unix/unix-socket-faq/unix-socket-faq-2.html#time_wait) reason.

In my application I want to add a procedure when the bind fails. this procedure should check at the beginning the type of the bind fails:

1. If the reason is due to the `TIME_WAIT`, then wait amoment and
   retry again.
2. If the reason is due to that the port is taken by another application, then choose another port and retry the bind

How I can know the type of the bind fails?

**NOTE:**

1. I do not want to use `SO_REUSEADDR`
2. the bind `errno` is the same for both type of fails

Comment: If you use `SO_REUSEADDR` you will avoid the errors due to `TIME_WAIT` but not those due to `LISTEN`, but I'm puzzled by your proposal to just try another port. What is the value of choosing another port? How are the clients going to know what the port is?

Comment: @EPJ, for my use case, there is only one client and there is a way to inform the client of the used port. Any way,  this is not the  issue

Comment: OK, so *why* don't you want to use SO_REUSEADDR? It's the *answer.* it does exactly what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I would use the `SO_REUSEADDR` sockopt on your listening socket to avoid this situation in the first place. `SO_REUSEADDR` will allow you to reuse the same socket your TCP server was using previously upon restart because it is still being held open by the operating system.

Secondly, error handling is always a good idea. I encourage you to check the return value of the `bind` and handle the most likely `errno` you expect to encounter. You can get an `errno` list for `bind` in section 2 of the man page.

```
$> man -s 2 bind
```

Finally, the `errno` for a socket in `TIME_WAIT` is the same `errno` as an address in use: `EADDRINUSE`. This is because a socket in `TIME_WAIT` is in use by the OS.